# Video from youtube in iframe doesn't work

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have to put video on website.I put video links from youtube on my website. I use iframe. And don't see any video. I see only screen with names of videos, but not a video.I use links which youtube gives. What can be a problem? Should I use something more in my code? I have to add something in meta to use iframe?

```css
.central-container{
    margin-left: 18.75%;
    margin-right: 18.75%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-for-all-videos{  
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.container-for-video{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 46%;
    min-width: 250px;   
}
.container-for-video h4{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 978px){
    .container-for-video:nth-child(odd){
        float: left;    
    }
    .container-for-video:nth-child(even){
        float: right;    
    }
    
}
@media (min-width: 440px){
    .bottom-info-container{
        
        margin: 50px auto 150px auto;          
    }
}
@media (max-width: 978px){   
    
    .container-for-video{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="central-container">
            <div class="container-for-all-videos">
                <div class="container-for-video">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N1z37KqpCc" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                    <h4>ד"ר אלדר על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAwB17JTIgs" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe>
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר מתארח אצל אלונה פרידמן על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMHpU-f3Kzo" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe>
                        <h4>ניתוח שרוול קיבה ע"י ד"ר אלדר</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ij0poiNEvw" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe>
                        <h4>ראיון נוסף של ד"ר אלדר אצל אלונה פרידמן</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfF-1tyG_uI&t=21s" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe>
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר על תוצאות ארוכות טווח של ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N1z37KqpCc" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe>
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: How do you call your website? With `http://` or `https://` ?

Comment: I still didn't put it on a server. So, it doesn't have http:// or https:// . But for the video I tried both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to youtube.com and click share then embed and copy the iframe source without doing it, it wont work as youtube as iframe block

```css
.central-container{
    margin-left: 18.75%;
    margin-right: 18.75%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-for-all-videos{  
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.container-for-video{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 46%;
    min-width: 250px;   
}
.container-for-video h4{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 978px){
    .container-for-video:nth-child(odd){
        float: left;    
    }
    .container-for-video:nth-child(even){
        float: right;    
    }
    
}
@media (min-width: 440px){
    .bottom-info-container{
        
        margin: 50px auto 150px auto;          
    }
}
@media (max-width: 978px){   
    
    .container-for-video{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="central-container">
            <div class="container-for-all-videos">
                <div class="container-for-video">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <h4>ד"ר אלדר על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר מתארח אצל אלונה פרידמן על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <h4>ניתוח שרוול קיבה ע"י ד"ר אלדר</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <h4>ראיון נוסף של ד"ר אלדר אצל אלונה פרידמן</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר על תוצאות ארוכות טווח של ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container-for-video">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rAwB17JTIgs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <h4>ד"ר אלדר על ניתוחים בריאטריים</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
```